# Why doesn't my jump script stop my player from jumping mid air?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour {

public float jumpSpeed;

private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

private bool _isGrounded = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //if the jump button was pressed
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && _isGrounded) {
        _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (
            _rigidbody.velocity.x,
            jumpSpeed
        );
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        _isGrounded = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionLeave2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        _isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

}

Its supposed to check if the player is on the ground, but it still lets my character jump unlimited times in the game.

Comment: Isn't the method "OnCollisionExit2D" not "OnCollisionLeave2D"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not setting your bool `_isGrounded` to false anywhere. As @DMGregory said, there is no such method as `OnCollisionLeave2D` defined in Unity API, thus it won't be executed unless called explicitly, which means, the bool `_isGrounded` will remain true and your player will continue to recieve jump input. You need to change it to [OnCollisionExit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit2D.html).